# Can't catch Primefaces selectOneListBox with request.getParameter

Tags: java, primefaces, request

I have a from where i need a Dropdown menu or a list mennu with 2 values: `EAIOTemplate` and `MVPTemplate`. Current I use the `<p:selectOneListbox>` with `Primefaces`.

First of all, this Listbox looks exrtremly ugly :
[image: ugly listbox]

And in the ListMenu (Primefaces Dropdown), i see no dropdown...

But when I send my from with something selected and i'll grab it with getParameter, it is always *null*

Here is my code:

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="templateId" value="EAIOTemplate" name="templateId">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="EAIOTemplate" itemValue="EAIOTemplate" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="MVPTemplate" itemValue="MVPTemplate" />
            </p:selectOneListbox>
```

And here is the getParameter = null. Expected is the value of the listbox.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/eap", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
public String handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String templateId = request.getParameter("templateId");
    (...)
```

So why this won't work?

Comment: Open the source code and look at the HTML Element of the Listbox. There you can see which id / name the requestHandler get.

Answer (score -1):

You used a direct `value="EAIOTemplate"`, but it suppose to be used with a variable like `value="#{myBean.templateValue}"`

And inside your MyBean:

```
public String getTemplateValue() {
   return this.templateValue;
}
public void setTemplateValue(String templateValue) {
   this.templateValue = templateValue;
}
```

Comment: There is no bean in the background. It is a stand alone site working with mvc... 
and why it shouldn't work with a static string?